# Crear script de un cuadro de base de datos

Tags: mysql

Quisiera que me ayuden a idenfiticar los simbolos de los caudros, no se como diferenciar en estos cuadros la relacion por ejemplo en otros cuadros dice si la relacion es de n a 1 o de n a m pero aqui no hay esto porfa es de urgencia[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [¿Bajo qué circunstancias puedo agregar "urgente" o frases similares a mi pregunta para obtener respuestas más rápido?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4771) Además, no sabemos qué se utilizó para dibujar el DER. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Sin saber nada de tu der, o que son esas cosas, por sentido comun, diria que esta todo ahi.. ahi te dice cuales relaciones son 1Xm... es mas.. al ver las tablas deberias poder entenderlo... por ejemplo, cual es la relacion entre las tablas provincias y paquetes???

Comment: La llave es 1, y el símbolo `8` es muchos